# Hide/Show function anchor and div

Tags: jquery, html

Referencing a past post and found the functions below that work perfect in the fiddle and what I would like to achieve, but, not on my current live site. Yes, jQuery is in the header of my current site. This strange issue is driving me nuts. Thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
<div><a href="#" id="btn">Show bank div and hide fancy div</a></div>
<div id="btn-bk"><a href="#">back</a></div>
<div id="bank">Bank Div</div>
<div id="fancy">Fancy Div</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
$('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#btn-bk').click(function(e){    
    $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#bank {display:none;}
#btn-bk {display:none;}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xmc32ay2/)

Comment: Without seeing the source for the live site, a diagnosis will be difficult. Post a URL?

Comment: Weird... Let´s focus in your current live site. Is your code executing after the dom renders? If your code is running before the dom rendering, it won´t work. An ideal scenario (not the cleaner way) will be to wrap everything into a $(document).on("ready", function () {}).. Try that...

Comment: added $(window).bind("load", function() { to render after page load and worked. Thank you Guillermo putting me on the right path! Appreciate it

Comment: Ac12, Use $(document).on("ready", function () {}); instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ac 12, great! But please wait, don´t use "load", "load" and "ready" are not the same thing. Ready is the option of choice because it's triggered when the dom was loaded. (This is also one of the reasons because is a good practice to include your code before the body close tag. All your dom will be processed, all your elements will be there, so no need of using $(document).on("ready", function () {}) if you´re putting scripts at the end of your document)

In order to give you the full working code, will be this:

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {

  $('#btn').on("click", function(e){    
    $('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });

  $('#btn-bk').on("click", function(e){    
      $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
          $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
      });
  });

});
```

I've also improved your code a little bit by removing .bind, and .click (always, always use .on), but remember, the cleaner way is to put your scripts at the end of the document, in that way you´ll avoid the .on("ready".

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using embedded code, so wrap it up:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(e){    
            $('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });

        $('#btn-bk').click(function(e){    
            $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment it was wrapped in a script tag. Cheers

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh If you compare the poster's code to my code, you will see a **HUGE** difference on one `<script>` tag which was wrapped around a close function `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

@ac12 Have you declared `$(document).ready(function(){});` ?

Comment: @Davion you're right and I know that but beginner is jQuery does not understand what is the different between them. you should describe your answer, not just paste the code here...